# make dictionary that will loop every 9 numbers. C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Im new to programming and sorry if I cant explain properly. I am trying to iterate through a list that has items in it in multiples of 9. So the list can have 9,18,27.. items.
I have the code working for it to read when there is 9 using this dictionary. But I would like it work for any amount in multiples of 9.

```
var alphabets = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                            {
                             {1,"A2"},{2,"B2"},{3,"C2"},{4"D2"},
                             {5,"E2"},{6,"F2"}, {7,"G2"},{8,"H2"},
                             {9,"I2"}
                    };
```

So for example if there was 18 items it would like this dictionary to have this function.

```
 var alphabets2 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                            {
                             {1,"A2"},{2,"B2"},{3,"C2"},{4"D2"},
                             {5,"E2"},{6,"F2"}, {7,"G2"},{8,"H2"},
                             {9,"I2"},
                             {10,"A3"},{11,"B3"},{12,"C3"},{13"D3"},
                             {14,"E3"},{15,"F3"}, {16,"G3"},{17,"H3"},
                             {18,"I3"}
                    };
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Comment: A Dictionary is a collection or data structure.  They do not loop and they do not have functions

Comment: To me it sounds like you just want a number -> text conversion with a bit of calculation involved. It doesn't seem like you really need to store anything. Though if you go that route your 1-9 sequence would have to be treated a little differently.

Comment: does this work for you? `var ndictionary = alphabets2.Where(a=> a.Key <= alphabets2.Where(x => x.Key % 9 == 0).Max(x => x.Key)).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);`

Comment: I think there's a pattern. ;)

Comment: *sorry if I cant explain properly* - your inexperience with programming has little to do with your ability to form coherent thoughts and write them down in a way that others can understand what you're thinking.. Don't try to use programming terms like "function" - you're using them incorrectly and causing confusion for us because we know what they truly mean, and they can't be used how you're using them. Show us your list of items. Show us your code you have. Tell us in plain terms how you get from what you have to what you want

Comment: Also like to point out that a dictionary that is indexed by an incrementing integer is relatively pointless; you should just use an array or list. These things are also indexed by an incrementing integer.. If you had your items as presented here in an array instead of a dictionary you can retrieve eg item with key N by doing `array[N-1]`

Answer (score 2):

As @DiplomacyNotWar commented, it sounds as if you need to input int value to convert to a correlating string value which is uniformly based on multiples of 9. If this is the case, I agree with @DiplomacyNotWar that you don't need to store anything but create a function to output the needed string value based on an int value. Here is a function that will output the pattern in your examples.

```
    // value should be 0
    string ConvertIntToSpecificString(int value)
    {
        // this will give you an int value 0-8
        var modValue = (value - 1) % 9;
        // The unicode for 'A' is 65
        var firstCharValue = (char)(65 + modValue);
        // This will return a whole number giving the iteration count. FE: 19 / 9 = 2
        // Adding 2 to fit the pattern stated in the examples.
        var secondValue = ( value / 9 ) + 2 ;
    
        return $"{firstCharValue}{secondValue}";
    }
```